# java - code is outputting ArrayList@40c84051?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to return a List of recipes that contain a certain ingredient, but my code gives me a weird output: ArrayList@40c84051.

How do I make it so that it outputs a list of recipes?

```
public List searchByIngredient(String target) {
   List result = new ArrayList();
   for (Object ingred : mList) {
      Recipe i = (Recipe) ingred;
      if (i.hasIngredient(target)) {
         result.addLast(ingred);
      }
   }
   return result;
 }
```

Comment: Please show us where you're actually doing the output.

Comment: Your `Recipe` class needs to implement the `toString()` method to display a String that represents the Recipe.

Comment: You should use parameters, if not for your own benefit, at least to help us understand your question `List<Recipe>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override  toString() in Recipe class.

```
public String toString()
{
    //Return Customized message of Recipe information.

    //such as,
    return String.format("Customized message format", args)

}
```

Then u try to print recipe object, it will print the Custom message you specified.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is likely the result of "System.out.println(recipeList.toString())" which simply prints the address of the ArrayList object.

You need to add a "toString()" method on the Recipe class, and then output the Recipes as follows:

```
ArrayList<Recipe> recipeList = ...
for (Recipe recipe : recipeList) {
    System.out.println(recipe);
}
```

And in your Recipe class

```
public String toString() {
    String description = "Ingredients: ";
    description+= ingredienets; 

    // put whatever description code here you like.

    return description;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A message like that is typically caused by calling `toString()` on an object that has not overridden the `Object.toString()` method.

But the puzzling thing is that `ArrayList` *does* override `toString()` ... or more precisely, the `AbstractList` does.

So I suspect that either you've misreported the output, or there is something really strange going on here.

Please show us the code that:

- produces the output, and
- creates the "stuff" that the output is produced from.

---

One possibility is that `ArrayList` is not the standard `java.util.ArrayList` but some custom class that you have written yourself ... and declared in the default package.  That would explain why there is no package name in the output.